# In a Maven project, a class in folder src/main/java can't resolve import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Tags: maven, selenium

I have a maven project for Selenium tests project. All the necessary dependencies were defined in pom.xml like

```
selenium-java
webdrivermanager
assertj-core
testng
maven-surefire-plugin
maven-failsafe-plugin
slf4j-api
slf4j-simple
```

Now, I wrote a helper class, which has to serve as a common utility for the selenium tests located in folder src/test/java. This class has one static method with WebElement as a parameter for that I tried to import org.openqa.*.*classes. I am getting **'import org.openqa can't be resolved'**

> If I keep the class/method inside a selenium test class with in
>   src/test/java folder it is resolving well. Why error is specific to
>   src/main/java folder classes ?

Comment: Check the scope defined for selenium dependency

Comment: It was 'test' scope.
<scope>test</scope>
Would this be a problem ? I commented it out and it got resolved.

Comment: I hope you don't have defined maven plugins (surefire, failsafe) as dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the comment in answer . To use the selenium dependency in classes defined in src/main/java folder Make sure scope is defined for project.

```
`<scope>test</scope>`
```

Remove above scope from selenium dependency

```
`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.5</version>
</dependency>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul L comment answered the question. I should be marking it as an answer.